# Bluemix task runner service capable of PHP

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a PHP web application which needs to process a lot of data which may take some minutes or more. I want to be able to start a background task which would do the processing and poll for the progress from the web-app.

On the normal hosting I would run a permanent process with

```
> nohup php runner.php &
```

I can not do this with IBM CF. I suppose there must be another Bluemix service which I can delegate long running tasks to. Is there?

Comment: once initiated does this process run forever?  If not, how is the process initiated?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the process to run forever or at least for 24h. It would receive tasks to do from the website by querying DB. So it's a single process which can run arbitrary function which is specified from outside.

Comment: Can you run runner.php as another php bluemix application?  If not, what about deploying runner.php as a docker service?

Comment: > Can you run runner.php as another php bluemix application?
That's what I need. How to make it execute ```php runner.php``` after startup instead or in parallel with apache?

Answer (score 0):

To run `runner.php` instead of apache, try creating a file `.bp-config/options.json` and setting these values:

```
"WEB_SERVER"    : "none"
"APP_START_CMD" : "php runner.php"
```

This is the default options.json file: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/defaults/options.json

More info: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html